# 2nd display not working on Windows 10 laptop

Tags: display, external

The DELL laptop has the following specification:

```
OS Name                          Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Version                          10.0.19041 Build 19041
OS Manufacturer                  Microsoft Corporation
System Manufacturer              Dell Inc.
System Model                     Latitude 5401
System Type                      x64-based PC
Processor                        Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9300H CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2400 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical 
BIOS Version/Date                Dell Inc. 1.11.1, 18/12/2020
SMBIOS Version                   3.2
Embedded Controller Version      255.255
BIOS Mode                        UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer.          Dell Inc.
Installed Physical Memory (RAM). 16.0 GB
Total Physical Memory            15.8 GB
Available Physical Memory        8.90 GB
Total Virtual Memory             18.2 GB
Available Virtual Memory         11.1 GB
Page File Space                  2.38 GB
```

The external monitor I have:

```
Samsung C49RG90 49-inch Super Ultrawide Curved Gaming Dual WQHD 1440p Monitor
```

I am connecting the monitor to the laptop using a HDMI cable.  The monitor appears in the Device Manager listed as a Generic PnP Monitor, the laptop display is also displayed as a Generic PnP Monitor.

If I open the Display Settings I can see both monitors are present and the second monitor is shown as a rectangle presentation that is scaled according to its size compared to the laptop with 1 shown in the laptop representation and 2 in the second display.  However nothing appears on the second display and it keeps flickering and flashing up HDMI on the display.  If I click the identify button a 1 is displayed on the laptop but nothing not the second display.

I know this monitor works and so does the cable because I have an iMAC on the same desk and if I connect the monitor to the iMAC using the same cable it works, but not on this laptop, what could be the issue?

Comment: If it flickers it may be a sign of unsupported mode selected for this monitor. Try to open Display settings and check the selected resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem, by trail and error, changed the fresh rate of the second monitor to 30Hz and it now works.

To confirm, this is 5120x1440 @ 30Hz